# Creating multiple instances of PhantomJS or only one?

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I have a script which needs to crawl a website. For every request(each URL), I initialize a new web driver with selenium/phantomJS .
Is this approach unscalable and will it cost a lot of CPU usage over time? 
Should I rather only create a single driver and save it somewhere in a global variable and reuse it for all the requests?
Will doing this lead to lower cpu usage or won't be much effective?

Answer (score 3):

> For every request(each URL), I initialize a new web driver with selenium/phantomJS . Is this approach unscalable and will it cost a lot of CPU usage over time?

This is definitely a problem. `PhantomJS` instances are usually heavy on CPU and it is not a reliable way to scale. If you can reuse the same "webdriver" instance without problems or a negative impact on the performance, do it. If not, look into making a [`Selenium grid`](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp) with multiple selenium nodes - workers that would actually have browser instances running. You can also look into using *remote selenium servers*, like [`BrowserStack`](https://www.browserstack.com) or [`Sauce Labs`](https://saucelabs.com/).

Answer (score 1):

PhantomJS has an embedded webserver ([Mongoose](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose)) that you can run and receive requests to. This avoids the need to initialize it every time. Warming up is quite costly in PhantomJS.

Here is a sample webserver code in PhantomJS that you could start with:

```
var port = 9494;
var server = require('webserver').create();
var page = require('webpage').create();

var your_method = function(data) {
    # Do stuff here
};

service = server.listen(port, function (request, response) {
  var input = JSON.parse(request.post);
  page.open(url, function (status) {
    page.evaluate(your_method, input)
});

if (service) {
  console.log('Server running on port ' + port);
} else {
  console.log('Error: Could not create web server listening on port ' + port);
  phantom.exit();
}
```

From the documentation;

> This is intended for ease of communication between PhantomJS scripts
>   and the outside world and is not recommended for use as a general
>   production server. There is currently a limit of 10 concurrent
>   requests; any other requests will be queued up.